# Como utilizar banco de dados no CakePHP sem obedecer às convenções de nomenclatura?

Tags: php, cakephp

O CakePHP possui convenções para a nomenclatura de tabelas, classes, etc., como por exemplo ter as colunas `username` e `password` para tabelas que guardam usuários. Em minha situação atual, tenho tabelas que não obedecem as esses padrões.

Como poderia continuar utilizando as facilidades e recursos do framework, sem modificar os nomes de todas as tabelas, e colunas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode forçar o nome da tabela na definição do model:

```php
class MeuModel extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'minha_tabela';
}
```

As colunas podem ter o nome que você quiser, e é recomendável que a tabela tenha uma PK com autoincrement chamada `id`. Se a sua PK tiver outro nome, é possível forçar um, mas precisa ser uma PK simples (ou seja, não composta por múltiplas colunas):

```php
class MeuModel extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'minha_tabela';
    public $primaryKey = 'minha_tabela_id';
}
```

Em relação às colunas `username` e `password`, os nomes podem ser configurados quando você inclui o componente `Auth` no Controller. Por exemplo, para utilizar um campo chamado `email` em vez de `username`:

```php
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Mais detalhes na [seção do manual sobre autenticação](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html).

Comment: No meu caso, a PK corresponde ao nome da tabela + _id, exemplo "usuarios_id", "eventos_id". Tem como contornar?

Comment: Tem sim @CalebeOliveira, veja minha resposta atualizada com um exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do @bfavaretto, não esqueça de chamar o model no controller.

```
QualquerController extends appController {
    // $uses atribui o model 'MEU'.
    public $uses = 'Meu';
}
```

Isso resolve o problema do inflector obrigar a chamar seu controller de 'Meus', para usar um model 'Meu'.